# make calls to HTTPS services in flutter , ios simulator throws CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: ios, https, dart, flutter, client-certificates

This is the error in my terminal 
VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: ok(handshake.cc:363)) #0 IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:30:23) #1 BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:171:38) #2 BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:56:5) #3 post. (package:http/http.dart:70:34) #4 _withClient (package:http/http.dart:167:20) #5 post (package:http/http.dart:70:3) #6 fetchEntriesFromProject (file:///Users/macsetup/Documents/flutterApps/testapi/lib/main.dart:137:34) #7 fetchUsersFromGitHub (file:///Users/macsetup/Documents/flutterApps/testapi/lib/main.dart:115:3) #8 ProjectListScreenState.build (file:///Users/macsetup/Documents/flutterApps/testapi/lib/main.dart:34:21) #9 StatefulElement.build (package<…>

Comment: Can you add more information about your question?

Comment: Which website are you trying to access?

Comment: actually its a in house app developed , the services are available via https...to access it on chrome I have to install a local certificate.Is there a process needed for ios simulater / android emulator to access https api's